# Strategy in Coloring a 4x4 empty grid and the one who completes any 2x2 area of the grid is the loser

Tags: strategy, game-theory

Alice and Bob are playing the following game: They have a 4x4 empty grid and take turns coloring one square each, starting with Alice. ***Assume that both players will colour the squares in with the same colour.*** Whoever completes any $2\times2$ area on the grid after having made their move, is the loser.

**Is there any winning strategy for either of the two players?**

Comment: This was flagged as off-topic; however I think adding the above clarity will resolve this issue. I have therefore edited the question per @philip's comments below to reflect that he intended both players to colour in squares with the same colour.

Comment: The same question was posted on a different stack by (apparently) a different user one hour earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2884764/5676

Comment: You also posted the answer seen on the math.se question here. I pointed out a mistake, then you posted that exact same comment on the math.se answer, then deleted your answer here.  That makes three things you've plagiarized so far.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I'm assuming that Bob and Alice are painting with different colors and that we are only concerned with a $2\times 2$ square of the same color. Now I realize that I may have interpreted the problem incorrectly.

> Bob

can always force a win or draw with the following strategy:

> Whatever square Alice colors, Bob should color the square symmetric with respect to the origin (rotate 180 degrees). This way, Bob can never complete a $2\times 2$ square unless Alice has just completed a rotated version of that square. In fact, Bob can win/draw this way on any $2n\times 2n$ grid.

Comment: this is a draw, not a win

Comment: This is wrong; What if Alice does the middle 2 squares of the second row? Then Bob would be the one to finish it

Comment: @PotatoLatte; so they use the same colour then?

Comment: I misunderstood the problem, assuming that Alice and Bob are painting with different colors, and we are only concerned with $2\times 2$ squares of the same color.

Comment: Well I didn't write the problem; So this may be right

Comment: No. If Alice select $(2,2)$, so Bob selects $(3,3)$. Alice selects $(2,3)$ and Bob selects $(3,2)$ completing a square and losing.

Comment: @philip that's what i thought

Comment: @PotatoLatte Then the given answer does not hold

Answer (score 3):

Bob wins if

> both Alice and Bob only colour the edges. Then Alice is eventually forced to play in the middle.

If Alice colours an inner cell for the first time:

> Bob colours the diagonally opposite, and reverts to the edge strategy ignoring the extremal corners of the extremal sub-grids with inner cells. We either end up with a saturated grid (Bob wins), or Alice colours one, and so Bob colours the opposite corner with the same effect.

Alice colours a second inner cell:

> Bob colours the opposite extremal corner, and the same strategy gives Bob the win.

Summary:

> Bob always wins.